# Is "bare from waist up" grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I just saw a sentence:

> Men protesting the law were **bare from waist up.**

I would write it as:

> Men protesting the law were **bare from above their waist.**

How would native speakers say it?

Thank you.

Comment: Bare from the waist up, or bare-chested.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey would you please tell me about "up" here? Is it an adverb meaning "upward"?

Comment: Where did you see the sentence?

Answer (score -1):

I think your second sentence is a little confusing, as it is not a standard way to write it so I would assume you are writing it that way in specific, and I would interpret it as more like

> Men protesting the law were bare from (some unknown spot) above their waist.

which would leave me a little confused about which part of them is actually bare!

Casually I would use "shirtless" or perhaps "bare-chested". "Bare from the waist up" sounds a little more stiff, like something a reporter would write.

Comment: Being "dead from the neck up", and "dead from the waist down" are derogatory things that are said about people, and are not at all "stiff".

Comment: I actually haven't ever heard those phrases before...that said, I think "bare from the waist up" just sounds stiff to me because I probably would never say that.

Comment: "Dead from the neck up" is a way of saying "stupid" or, I suppose, "unimaginative", and "dead from the waist down" means sexually dull.

Comment: As a native UK English speaker, I view "Bare from the waist up." as idiomatic. I do agree that for some reason it is rather stilted. Perhaps we need to understand why it is remarkable that men would be partially undressed, and then terms like "shirtless" and "bare-chested" seem to bring more colour. To be shirtless in the dining room? Unthinkable!

Comment: I think "Bare from the waist up" makes it clear there is nothing on the top half of the body **at all** (and seems completely natural as a BrE speaker). '*Bare-chested*' could just be a shirt unbuttoned and open at the front. '*Shirtless*' could mean they have taken their shirt off, but might still have a vest on (imo)